# How to get Udemy type video controls?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a video tutorial player website, in that I require video player to  display the controls and the contents of the course as per a udmey course tutorial video player. [If we click the menu button a side div appears for the course description and on clicking the close button it closes the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3s4t.png). Please help me in this using CSS.
PS: Refer the image.

Comment: Please show us something that you've tried yet.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soulshaker9513/5sozumgy/